# How to configure Delphi to debug a dll with a different name to the project

Tags: c++, delphi, debugging, dll

I'm translating C++ code into Delphi code. (handmadehero.org)
In the project, the executable checks the modified date of a dll file.
If the ddl (handmade.dll) has changed since the last check, it unloads the dll (handmade_temp.dll), makes a copy (handmade.dll -> handmade_temp.dll) and loads it again.

This way you can make changes to the dll code, compile it and have the changes show up in the running application immediately.

When you run the C++ application, in visual studio debugger, you can set a break point in the dll and it will break. In my delphi application, it does not break at the breakpoint, because the handmade.dll was not loaded by the application, handmade_temp.dll was loaded.
Is there a way I can tell the delphi debugger, that even though the compiled output file is handmade.dll, the debugger has to check that handmade_temp.dll is loaded and use that for debugging?

The only change that was required for visual studio was a compiler switch that set the name of the .pdb file to be handmade(random number).pdb.
The presenter of the series uses emacs to edit the code, the command line to compile (cl) and visual studio to debug.

Comment: I think you could to this by using of Post-Build events which alows you to execute custom commands.

Comment: Thought I should add that I am using version XE7

Comment: If I understand correctly, you switch the DLL on runtime and want to debug the new DLL.  If thats the case, using "Attach To Process" under run _after_ you switch DLL might help.

Comment: So I learnt that part of why it works in VS is beacuse the path to the pdb file is embeded in the dll file. When the file is loaded the debugger knows where to find the debug symbols. How it knows that the source is linked to it, I dont know yet.